# How to show an object that is outside of the artboard on the master page on all created pages? *INDESIGN

Tags: adobe-indesign, artboard, master-page

I'm trying to add a group of graphic elements next to the artboard (page) that would be used on each created page. I tried to place the group next to the artboard on the master page, but it doesn't show up on the pages (see screenshots - the yellow triangle is placed on the master page and is supposed to be visible on the regular page).

Does anyone have an idea how to make the objects that are outside of the artboard on the master page visible on all pages created with this master page?

Master Page:

[image]

Regular page:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2):

If you place an empty rectangle in the artboard area that only just encroaches into the bleed area, then it will appear on all pages that rely on that master page.

Grouping any other items with the rectangle will bring them along with it.

Comment: you can always set the bleed for the doc even if you don't intend to use it

Answer (score 0):

InDesign used to have the feature you mentioned before and then it stopped doing it. Here's the solution I figured out.

Apply a slug to your whole document and now everything inside of your slug area on the parent page will apply to the regular pages.